# How to redrop the letters on the letters rack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

After dropping the letters on the board letters are not pacing on the letters rack again. It only bounded on the board after placing. Can I place the letters on the board also re drag the letters on the rack if needed. how does it possible ?
Here is the link : http://www.onlinedemowebsite.com/design/swatch/drag-and-drop/try3.html 
Thanks

```
$(element).draggable({
                containment:'.board ,.lettersContainer',
                snap:true,
                tolerance:'touch',
                snap:'.cellBox', snapMode: 'center',
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code you probably will want to fiddle with the [containment option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) of the Draggable jQueryUI component when dragging is initiated from the board. Now the droptarget is probably confined to the board while you'll want to confine it to the board AND the rack.

Comment: Thanks,
I have tried to give two containment area but it is not working when drop the letters on the board. 
'$(element).draggable({
                 containment:'.board ,.lettersContainer',
     snap:true,
     tolerance:'touch',
     snap:'.cellBox', snapMode: 'center',
                });'

Comment: Try setting no containment at all and see if it works then, can you drag the element all the way to the rack? Also make sure the rack is implementing the Droppable plugin.

Comment: thanks for your advice, just i wanted to know does it possible to keep the letters either on board or on letter rack? besides this if it is place it will back to letters rack.

Comment: Have anybody got any solutions? It will be helpful for me if any one help me to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance